# Wine Installation - Unmet Dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

After having read every single forum/question on this particular issue, I'm at my wits end with trying to install Wine on my system. Usually I can get around things by reading up guides and answers but I'm stumped on this one.

After entering the following commands (as instructed here https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo mv winehq.key /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key

wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/winehq-focal.sources
sudo mv winehq-focal.sources /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

sudo apt update 

sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

I always end up with the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 7.6~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In case this is useful, I'm including a neofetch output:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Host: UX430UNR 1.0 
Kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic 
Uptime: 48 mins 
Packages: 2018 (dpkg) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 
WM: KWin 
WM Theme: Breeze 
Theme: Breeze Dark [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: breeze-dark [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: Hack 11 
CPU: Intel i7-8550U (8) @ 4.000GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX150 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
Memory: 2931MiB / 15862MiB
```

Thank you in advance for your time and advice.
I'm looking forward to hearing from you!

Noelind